# iOS Enterprise distribution error - “cannot connect to server”?

Tags: ios, iis, ssl, enterprise

I have an iOS application packaged for enterprise distribution on an IIS server.

- The IIS server uses HTTPS.
- I've set the MIME types correctly for **ipa** and **plist** files.
- I've downloaded and installed the IIS server's SSL certificate on the test iOS device.
- The IIS server uses form authentication to access all files by default.

When I login and try to click on the download/install link in Safari on the test iOS device, I get the following error: "**Cannot connect to xxxxx.xxxxx.com**"

When anonymous (no authentication is needed) access is set for both the **plist** and for the **ipa** files. iOS will download and install the application correctly.

**My question is:** How can I secure the **plist** and **ipa** files and get iOS to correctly download and install the application?